# timestamps is inserting 0 values

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp

I dont understand why my timestamps has no value...

*patient_data migration file*

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('patients', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->increments('pID');
            $table->string('pName');
            $table->string('pAddress');
            $table->string('pBday');
            $table->string('pPhone');
            $table->string('pEcon');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

*my database*

[image]

i changed created_at column to pDreg

I checked everything and im confident that my codes are correct.. but i still get no values please

Comment: If the timestamps should be set to the current date and time you should use `CURR_TIMESTAMP` as default value, phpmyadmin gives this as a choice in the dropdown of default value

Comment: It worked! thanks alot  :)

Comment: I'm going to make it an answer for future people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the timestamp columns should be set to the current date and time you should use `CURR_TIMESTAMP` as default value, phpmyadmin gives this as a choice in the dropdown of default value.

**SQL**

```
ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY `column` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
```

This sets the column to type of TIMESTAMP and field is automatically set to the current timestamp when you insert into the table.

Answer (score 1):

Your field type is set to DATETIME (thats why there is a date like 0000-00-00 shown), if you want to use a unix timestamp as your field's value, you should change this to an INT. 
Otherwise you should use the MySQL function NOW() for the current date and time (or $table->string(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); if you prefer using PHP for that).